# Open New View iOS App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this is absolutely a duplicate but nothing has worked for me. Now this is a very simple task yes, but I just can't figure it out. All I am trying to do is open a new view on a button press. When I tap the button it crashes

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
    UIViewController *WebViewController = [[UIViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self presentViewController:WebViewController animated:YES completion: nil];
}
```

**Error**

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x9829be0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key webView.'
```

Comment: Your controller (ViewController) needs to be embedded in a navigation controller.

Comment: @rdelmar: How would one go about that, can't find any good resources.

Comment: -1 ("this question does not show any research effort") for "can't find any good resources"; the web is *full* of good resources, and so is your local or online bookstore. Also for "it crashes" without providing a crash log or error message.

Comment: Why not use a segue? It would give you more room to play with (and easy to manage graphically)

Comment: @CaptJak That's not a bad recommendation, but if you can't successfully instantiate a view controller I don't think avoiding the issue is the right solution. Storyboards and segues are great, but anyone working with iOS should learn the basics.

Comment: The web may have good resources as Caleb said, but it's no substitute for the documentation, which you obviously haven't read. You should read the documents that are linked to at the top of the UIViewController Class Reference and the one at the top of the UITableView Class Reference. These are very extensive documents that will give you a good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't given us a lot to go on, but an educated guess is that you've specified some UIViewController subclass as the class of the File's Owner proxy in your .xib file, and you've connected one or more objects in the .xib to outlets in File's Owner. In your code, however, you're instantiating `UIViewController` rather than your subclass. UIViewController doesn't have the same set of outlets that your subclass does, so when the .xib loading mechanism tries to connect objects from the .xib to your view controller it throws an exception because `UIViewController` isn't KVC compliant for a key (same name as one of your outlets) or is missing a selector.

A good place to start is to look in the Console in Xcode when you run the program. You should see an error message there if your app crashes.

You should also [add a breakpoint for All Exceptions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010433-CH1-SW1) in Xcode's Breakpoints Navigator, so that you break when an exception is thrown.

You can get crash logs from the device in Xcode's [Organizer window](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-general/AbouttheOrganizerWindow/AbouttheOrganizerWindow.html), and these generally give you a stack trace and a pretty good idea of why your app crashed.

Answer (score 0):

Is your `buttonTapped` method actually hooked up to the button you want to click on?

Is `self.navigationController` `nil`, or not?

The above are two possibilities. You can use something like `NSLog()` to answer both those questions.

Comment: My buttonTapped method is hooked up, confirmed with NSLog(). Logging on self.navigationController produces no output.